# Timeout after gulp serve command

Tags: javascript, timeout, reactjs, gulp

I'm new in ReactJS and Gulp... .

I have a problem with `Gulp`. my problem is that when I write `gulp serve` in terminal, in the browser, my page doesn't show anything and the page doesn't load completely and after a long time with loading status, the browser show me:

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

message.

I don't know whats my problem?

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "projectOverview",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "gulp serve"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.2",
    "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-open": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "reactify": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

and I config gulpfile.js like as follow:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    open = require("gulp-open"),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    port = process.env.port || 3031;

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  gulp.src('./app/src/js/components/main.js')
      .pipe(browserify({ transform: 'reactify' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/dist/js'));
});

//launch browser in a part
gulp.task('open', function(){
  var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:' + port,
  };
  gulp.src('./app/index.html')
      .pipe(open('',options));
});

//live reload server
gulp.task('connect', function(){
  connect.server({
    root: 'app',
    port: port,
    livereload: true
  });
});

//live reload js
gulp.task('js', function(){
  gulp.src('./app/dist/**/*.js')
      .pipe(connect.reload());
});

//live reload html
gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src('./app/*.html')
      .pipe(connect.reload());
});

//watch files for live reload
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('app/dist/js/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('app/index.html', ['html']);
  gulp.watch('app/src/js/**/*.js', ['browserify']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);

gulp.task('serve', ['browserify', 'connect', 'open', 'watch']);
```

[image]

**Note** that this is a Test project and the `main.js` file is empty and it just contain *pragma*:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
```

and It should be show *ddddd* message, if it successfully load. 
I think my problem is in the paths that I set in index.html or gulpfile.js. but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved!

my mistake was from 2 part: 
 1.
I must run two command before calling `gulp serve`: first:
`gulp` 
and after that, 
`npm i` 
in terminal.

2.
My Kerio VPN was enable during test. after disconnecting from VPN account, it works perfect! I think the kerio application and gulp port, has conflict... .